# Fill Blank Row in a specific column with value from another column using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

If I have the following pandas dataframe

```
      A     B
0     Cat   Dog
1     Mouse Mouse
2     Fish  "Blank"
```

How do I parse through column B, identify that there is a blank value and then if there is a blank value fill in the blank with "Fish", so the desired data frame is:

```
      A     B
0     Cat   Dog
1     Mouse Mouse
2     Fish  Fish
```

Comment: By "Blank", is it really the word `"Blank"` or do you mean the empty string `''` or a null value recoginized by pandas (like `np.NaN`, or `None`).

Comment: `df['B'].mask(df['B']=='Blank').fillna(df['A')`?

Comment: This does not work

Answer (score 6):

You could try this -

```
import numpy as np
df['B'] = np.where(df['B'] == 'Blank', df['A'], df['B'])
```

Comment: This works! Thanks so much. Just a follow-up to that: Lets say instead of "Blanks" we actually have to look for blank values and then replace. I used an empty string " ", like so : df['B'] = np.where(df['B'] == ' ', df['A'], df['B']) but this did not work. Any ideas?

Comment: You are welcome ! It actually depends. If you had developed the dataframe after reading from a file, try replacing the empty string with np.nan i.e. `df['B'] = np.where(df['B'] == np.nan, df['A'], df['B'])`. Also, check if the `blank` is empty or does have a single space. In case of a single space, try replacing the empty string with a single space.

Answer (score 0):

- If only want to check from 'Blank' elements in column B:

`df[df['B'] == 'Blank'] = 'Fish'`

- Check to entire dataframe:

`df[df=='Blank'] = 'Fish'`